# DICOM file segmentation in Matlab. Export 4d to 3d?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-conversion, medical-imaging

I would like to segment a medical case using Image Segmenter. I know how to do this, but I need a 3D file in workspace. I am using the Dicom viewer to read the folder with the dicom files. Unfortunately, it only exports 4d. How can I turn it into 3d?

This is what I try to do: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/segment-lungs-from-3-d-chest-mri-data.html
And this function needs 3D image:

```
V = histeq (V);

BW = activecontour (V, mask, 100, „Chan-Vese” );

segmentedImage = V. * single (BW);
```

Maybe I can use other function? If yes, which one?

Comment: does this [answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/380190-convert-dicom-video-4d-to-3d-matrix) answers your question?

Comment: yes, it's work now. Thank u